# Rollback after Insert in Spring Test

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing

I am making test of my spring application, I am inserting data to db while test the application.
But how to rollback I don't know.

Test Code :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring.cfg.xml")
public class SpringAppTest{
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert(){
        //insert code
    }
}
```

Guide Me Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Following annotation before class :

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager",defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
```

here txManager is application context's Transaction Manager.

Here txManager is an instance or bean id of Transaction manager from application context.

```
    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```